# Accessing parent element of CSS selector result?

Tags: javascript, css

`var x = document.querySelector("div.tab-content a[href^='tel:+61 8 9306']")`  gets me the first match (and there is one). Is there a simple way, given the content of `x` to discover extra data about the `div.tab-content`? Ordinarily one would be using such a CSS to get access to the child but I'm wanting to get access to the parent of that particular child.

Comment: Please add more details about what you intend to get. Also provide the code in form of a [repro] including the necessary HTML to understand the context of the question